# Mii Plaza mini games have different names worldwide than in the US, can the tags be synonymised?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The *Streetpass Mii Plaza* minigames currently use their US names, but worldwide they are known by other titles (see the [Mii Plaza Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StreetPass_Mii_Plaza)).

Can we synonymise these two groups for ease of searching?

The tags are:

- [find-mii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-mii) / [streetpass-quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-quest)
- [flower-town](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flower-town) / [streetpass-garden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-garden)
- [mii-force](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mii-force) / [streetpass-squad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-squad)
- [warriors-way](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warriors-way) / [streetpass-battle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-battle)
- [monster-manor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-manor) / [streetpass-mansion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-mansion)
- [battleground-z](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battleground-z) / [streetpass-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-zombies)

(For completeness sake, [puzzle-swap](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-swap) is known by that name worldwide)

Comment: For the record, I'd prefer the other way around.

Comment: @FEichinger - me too, but I figured that all of the US tags are currently being used, whereas only one of the worldwide ones is.

Comment: Unless we want to adopt a policy of being US-centric, we should definitely synonymise to the worldwide names.

Comment: But if you synonymise to worldwide names, you somewhat lose all the American/Canadian search traffic. The [Super Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com) used to name their pages based on whatever English name came out first, but for search traffic purposes [they went to North American for everything](http://www.mariowiki.com/MarioWiki:Naming).

Comment: @Toomai - I was under the impression that the synonimised tags still existed (SEO and all that), they just redirected to the main tag. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I've reversed the tags so that the worldwide names take precedence, due to the larger number of upvotes/comments to that effect

Comment: Being in Britain, I definitely prefer a worldwide approach. It's hard enough to find stuff online which isn't UScentric as it is, what with most of the gaming industry being based there and all that. (nope, not bitter that Minecon's in LA and I can't afford the plane. Not at all.)

Comment: Let's also not ignore that Nintendo itself is *not* US-based. (I'm of course not suggesting that we start using Japanese names now, but we most definitely shouldn't assume the US to be the decisive region here.)

Comment: The synonimization direction should be based on the traffic we get. Does someone have those numbers available?

Comment: Oh yeah, and synonymizing these from NTSC -> PAL would also open up a whole can of precedents, such as [tag:kirby-super-star] -> [tag:kirbys-fun-pack], [tag:star-fox-64] -> [tag:lylat-wars], and [tag:super-mario-strikers] -> [tag:mario-smash-football].

Comment: @FEichinger [Based on Google Trends, the US search terms get searched for *a lot* more often than the generic names,](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=find%20mii%2C%20%20streetpass%20quest%2C%20%20mii%20force%2C%20%20streetpass%20squad&cmpt=q#q=find%20mii%2C%20streetpass%20quest%2C%20mii%20force%2C%20streetpass%20squad&cmpt=q) so I would definitely say to use those like originally suggested and like currently being used. Also, Stack Exchange is based in the US, so it makes sense there too.

Comment: @Toomai [Google Trends agrees with you.](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=find%20mii%2C%20%20streetpass%20quest%2C%20%20mii%20force%2C%20%20streetpass%20squad&cmpt=q#q=find%20mii%2C%20streetpass%20quest%2C%20mii%20force%2C%20streetpass%20squad&cmpt=q)

Comment: @Toomai - I don't think there will be a precedent set, it will depend on a game-by-game basis, and people will be arguing from either side just like on this question. For example, Genesis has been the top tag since the get-go, with mega-drive as a synonym. I'm not suggesting we reverse that (not here at least)

Comment: @Robotnik: I'm pretty sure we just use the US names for everything. Stack Exchange is an American company. [Our official policy on spelling in tags is to always use the American spelling.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us)

Comment: @Ullallulloo - Spelling is a far cry from names though, If there were a game called *Colours* (with a 'u') we would spell it that way in the tag, regardless of what region it was in. The reverse is true as well, for example, Gameboy Color

Comment: @Robotnik: Yeah, because that's the official name, but if there's multiple correct ways, we use the US option generally. [Google Trends showing that people search for the US names more anyway.](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=find%20mii%2C%20%20streetpass%20quest%2C%20%20mii%20force%2C%20%20streetpass%20squad&cmpt=q#q=find%20mii%2C%20streetpass%20quest%2C%20mii%20force%2C%20streetpass%20squad&cmpt=q)

Comment: @Robotnik: I don't think that Google could use synonyms at all...

Answer (score 6):

Why don't we just avoid the US vs Worldwide debate and use [streetpass-mii-plaza](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-mii-plaza) for all the minigames?  Just leave off the individual tags.

We don't have individual tags for [wii-bowling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wii-bowling) and [wii-tennis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wii-tennis).  We just have [wii-sports](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wii-sports).  If Mii Plaza is one application with multiple minigames, I don't see why we should treat it differently.

It really seems like we are overcomplicating things here.

Comment: Two more games were added to the Streetpass Plaza today. I think this is the course we should take if we don't want a mess of 16 tags for the plaza and its games.

Comment: I don't think we should reduce each minigame tag as a mere synonym of "Streetpass Mii Plaza". I'd suggest only, for example, "streetpass-battle" and "warriors-way" as synonyms.

Answer (score 4):

Use USA over Worldwide

- [find-mii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-mii) <- [streetpass-quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-quest)
- [flower-town](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flower-town) <- [streetpass-garden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-garden)
- [mii-force](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mii-force) <- [streetpass-squad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-squad)
- [warriors-way](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warriors-way) <- [streetpass-battle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-battle)
- [monster-manor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-manor) <- [streetpass-mansion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-mansion)

Answer (score 3):

Use Worldwide over USA

- [streetpass-quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-quest) <- [find-mii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-mii)
- [streetpass-garden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-garden) <- [flower-town](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flower-town)
- [streetpass-squad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-squad) <- [mii-force](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mii-force)
- [streetpass-battle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-battle) <- [warriors-way](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warriors-way)
- [streetpass-mansion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-mansion) <- [monster-manor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-manor)

Comment: Uh, does this mean use US tags over WorldWide tags (Worldwide becomes a synonym of US, so we tag with US), or the other way? Why must there be no good way to explain this?

Comment: @TheUgly Usually, the arrow points *from* the synonym *to* the master. ;)

Comment: @TheUgly - I've made this clearer in the description

Comment: -1, [Google says that Find Mii and Mii Force both have at least eight times as many searches as Streetpass Quest and Streetpas Squad](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=find%20mii%2C%20%20streetpass%20quest%2C%20%20mii%20force%2C%20%20streetpass%20squad&cmpt=q#q=find%20mii%2C%20streetpass%20quest%2C%20mii%20force%2C%20streetpass%20squad&cmpt=q), and [Stack Exchange's official policy is to the use the US terms when there are multiple valid ways](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us).

Comment: @Ullallulloo: No, that's not what that MSO post says.  Only US _spelling_ should be preferred in a tag if a term is recognized worldwide.  As an example I'm pulling straight out of thin air, on photography.SE, a the tag would be [color] and not [colour].  The globally recognized terms are [streetpass...] and not the other versions.  It's only in the US (and possibly the rest of NA) that use these second versions.

Comment: @MBraedley: Except they don't say to use the international terms either. It would be assumed that US terms would be used too if the spelling is. [Photography.SE *does* use \[color\] over \[colour\]](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color). You say that only the US using them means that we shouldn't use them, but like I said, that those are by far the most popular searches, which is the most important thing, and directly contrary to your point of using the international tags for popularity.

Comment: @Ullallulloo And that's what we have synonyms for. We should always default to International terms with US spelling.

Comment: @Ullallulloo: Do you know why the spelling was standardized _4 years ago_ on SO to use US English?  It's because most (all?) programming languages and the APIs written for them use US spelling.  Because I use them daily, Java and C++ are the first to come to mind.  But that has **absolutely no bearing** on what we're doing, since we're not arguing about the spelling of a word in a tag, we're arguing about the term used in a tag.  Don't think the two are equivalent.  Please, stop using "because MSO tells us to use US English" as part of your argument,  because you're wrong.

Comment: @Ullallulloo: Now, as for the second half of your comment, I didn't say we should be using the international terms because they're popular (they currently obviously aren't), but because they're **international!**  If I go shopping in another country, I don't ask for a tuque or a beanie (which is different, BTW), I ask for a winter hat, so that I'm understood.

Comment: @MBraedley Based on Google, the US terms are more well-understood. We don't use Lycan Wars just because it's  international. Since this is a US site, I don't see why we would use more obscure terms just because they're international.

Comment: @Ullallulloo SE inc. is a US company, SE is an international site.