# Let's clean up the Streetpass Mii Plaza minigame tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

6 years ago (wow!) I asked [whether we should synonymise the Streetpass Mii Plaza names](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7494/28182). The reason? The games were localised differently in the US, with each minigame gaining a completely different name from their worldwide counterparts.

We attempted to synonymise them, but the discussion petered out without any real consensus as to which way we should go (US-centric or Worldwide), and the highest-voted option (just use the main [streetpass-mii-plaza](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-mii-plaza) tag), was largely ignored by the community.

The end result? A real mess. Some questions use the US names, some the worldwide names. Some are synonymised and others are treated as completely separate games.

I think it's time to clean it up. With the ability to have 35-character long tags, I'd like to propose a solution that wasn't available to us back in 2013: **combining the names into one longer tag**. This is what it would look like:

- [streetpass-quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-quest), [find-mii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-mii) → [streetpass-quest-find-mii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-quest-find-mii) (25)
- [streetpass-quest-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-quest-2), [find-mii-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-mii-2) → [streetpass-quest-find-mii-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-quest-find-mii-2) (27)
- [streetpass-garden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-garden), [flower-town](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flower-town) → [streetpass-garden-flower-town](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-garden-flower-town) (29)
- [streetpass-squad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-squad), [mii-force](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mii-force) → [streetpass-squad-mii-force](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-squad-mii-force) (26)
- [streetpass-battle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-battle), [warriors-way](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warriors-way) → [streetpass-battle-warriors-way](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-battle-warriors-way) (30)
- [streetpass-mansion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-mansion), [monster-manor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-manor) → [streetpass-mansion-monster-manor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-mansion-monster-manor) (32)
- [streetpass-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-zombies), [battleground-z](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battleground-z) → [streetpass-zombies-battleground-z](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streetpass-zombies-battleground-z) (34)

This I feel will solve a couple of issues.

- Give us one dedicated tag per minigame, combining currently separate tags
- Solve the debate of US vs Worldwide naming by making it a non-issue
- Give us better SEO (as page titles have the first tag added to them so we'll list both names in every title)

I'm happy to action this but I'd like to hear the community's thoughts first: what do you think?

Comment: While we're at it, are there other games with worldwide/US name discrepancies that can benefit with the same treatment?

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Its definitely something we can consider case-by-case I think. I'd be wary of changing tags for instances where one name is more common over others, but if you have some tags you want changed, best to raise it as a [meta-tag:tag-rename-request] :)

Comment: This sounds like a good solution to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's been a week and with an overwhelmingly positive response to this meta via upvotes and comments, I've gone ahead and made the new tags + synonyms as listed in the question above.

Thanks team!